# Copying a column from one dataframe to another and join it based on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

**What I would like to do:**

I need to append values from a second dataframe to the first one based on the dates and forward-fill it using the `ffill` function on pandas. However I can't find a way to merge the data based on DateTime index as the index are of different formats.

I have an original dataframe with 5 min time series data (df) onto which I would like to append a column named `pivot` which has values computed on the daily time frame (day_df)

The original df:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Symbol
Date                        
2022-08-23 07:00:00 21255.3 21278.8 20911.0 20955.1 44548.837   BTCUSDT
2022-08-23 08:00:00 20955.2 21078.4 20874.8 21068.9 34545.958   BTCUSDT
2022-08-23 09:00:00 21069.0 21300.0 21057.0 21297.3 34938.504   BTCUSDT
2022-08-23 10:00:00 21297.2 21511.5 21297.2 21444.2 55520.111   BTCUSDT
2022-08-23 11:00:00 21444.3 21546.5 21279.0 21430.2 47976.229   BTCUSDT
```

The daily df containing the columns named pivot which I need to join to the smaller time frame df:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   pivot
Datetime                    
2022-09-26  18803.900391    19274.873047    18721.285156    19221.037109    18843.519531
2022-09-27  19221.839844    20338.455078    18915.667969    19105.250000    19271.420573
2022-09-28  19101.373047    19688.343750    18553.296875    19427.175781    19164.024740
2022-09-29  19431.128906    19587.783203    18924.353516    19566.023438    19468.287760
2022-09-30  19573.224609    20109.314453    19265.662109    19431.542969    19535.820964
```

**My approach:**
I thought of doing `pd.merge` however it does not seem to `ffill` the pivot values accordingly:

```
df.merge(day_df['pivot], how = 'cross')
```

Any help or a better solution would be appreciated.

**My complete code:**

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', period = '30d', interval = '30m')
df = df.reset_index()

#resetting df to start at midnight of next day
min_date = df.Datetime.min()
NextDay_Date = (min_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
df = df[df.Datetime >= NextDay_Date].copy()
df = df.set_index('Datetime')

day_df = (df.resample('D')
               .agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}))
day_df['pivot'] = (df['High']+ df['Low'] + df['Close'])/3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If anyone get's into the same issue as mine in the future, here's how I worked through it:**

I managed to figure it out for now by appending 00:00:00 to the daily time frame `day_df` df and the trying to use merge by converting to datetime format.
i.e by slightly modifying the `day_df` and appending HH:MM:SS to it so that it has the same format ast the smaller df. Following that, the joined df's nan values are forward filled using `fillna`.

```
day_df = day_df.reset_index()
day_df['Datetime'] = day_df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day_df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(day_df['Datetime'])
day_df = day_df.set_index('Datetime')
day_df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#merging both dataframes
df = df.join(day_df)
df['pivot'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

**Here's the complete code:**

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', period = '30d', interval = '30m')
df = df.reset_index()

#resetting df to start at midnight of next day
min_date = df.Datetime.min()
NextDay_Date = (min_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
df = df[df.Datetime >= NextDay_Date].copy()
df = df.set_index('Datetime')

# resampled daily pivots merged to smaller timeframe
day_df = (df.resample('D')
               .agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}))
day_df['pivot'] = (df['High']+ df['Low'] + df['Close'])/3

day_df = day_df.reset_index()
day_df['Datetime'] = day_df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day_df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(day_df['Datetime'])
day_df = day_df.set_index('Datetime')
day_df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#merging both dataframes
df = df.join(day_df)
df['pivot'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```